# Microsoft-graph-api, SSO and ADAL mobile sdk

Tags: mobile, single-sign-on, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I have developed few iOS/Android app using Azure Ad SDK 'ADAL'.

The app works properly for SSO feature and other login mechanisms. However now I want to add 'new contact' using Azure ad access token. But I came to know that Azure ad graph is no longer supported hence latest Microsoft Graph is suggested sdk for the same.

**My issue is: The most important feature according to me is the Single Sign-On feature with respect to mobile apps SDK  Azure ad SDK offers API for most convenient login user experience. Thus you are free to pick account from Authenticator app (if present) or any other app in the device which is already logged in.**

But Microsoft Graph SDK does not support Authenticator app available on the mobile phone. And prompts user a Login screen though he has already logged in to other app having outlook/Microsoft login

Please help me with some more information on this use case so that I can migrate to Microsoft graph from Azure Ad app.

**I have a huge tradeoff as follow**

*1.* Azure ad supports SSO but does not support Latest Graph features like: Adding new contact in 'My Contacts'

*2.* Microsoft Graph being Latest library/SDK has all features EXCEPT SSO.

Please provide me answers for these question of any suggestion if I am missing anything.

Comment: I am in need of help for the following question. Can you please check it out?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815169/adal-sdk-for-webview-android-for-sso

Answer (score 0):

The Graph SDKs do not contain any helpers for authentication/authorization.  For that you need to use either ADAL or MSAL to acquire tokens to use with Microsoft Graph (to instantiate a `GraphClient` object).  Please take a look at some of our Microsoft Graph samples. [NOTE the Azure AD **Graph** SDK also relied on ADAL or other mechanisms to acquire tokens and does not do this for you].  Here are the iOS samples:  https://github.com/search?q=ios+sample+user:microsoftgraph&type=Repositories

Also Azure AD Graph does not support personal contacts - this is ONLY supported by Microsoft Graph.

If you want to see an integrated client library, where token acquisition is implicitly taken care of as part of `GraphClient` instantiation then please post a request on UserVoice for this feature.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Is there any way to have this explicitly. What I mean, is it possible to have some mixed or hybrid way to initiate GraphClient object, Instead of waiting for Microsoft to include this use case in future

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT, I am expecting a help from you for integrating ADAL SDK in my application. Can you please check the question in the following link?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815169/adal-sdk-for-webview-android-for-sso